# Bypass Login View if Parse User is Logged In

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to create a function where upon app launch, the app checks to see if there is a Parse user currently logged in, and if this is true, then the user should bypass the login screen and taken to my view located within a tabbed view controller. If there is not user currently logged in, then open the login view, which opens on app load by default. I took a crack at this functionality by creating an if statement within the viewWillAppear function on my login view and if this is true, then `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()`, but my app crashes immediately due to no identifier with my name.

```
reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7ffbf3e82190>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ProfileSettingsViewController'
```

Now I might be missing something, but where do I set the identifier for a view controller? Or is my Class name the identifier as I currently assume?

In a related question, is this the best way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Here is my login controller logic:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

        if currentUser != nil {
           self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileSettingsViewController")   
        }        
}
```

Here is the view that should open if user is already logged in `ProfileSettingsViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileSettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

        //self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Profile Settings"
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "ffff"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        PFUser.logOut()
        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userLoggedOut", sender: self)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)

    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 7):

I haven't used Parse before, but for authorization I generally let AppDelegate to take care of the initial view controller.

```
// member variables
var storyboard : UIStoryboard?;

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle());
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileSettingsViewController");
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am pretty sure this will work from inside the view controller because in your code, you didn't assign the instantiated controller to the root view controller. However, I think AppDelegate should take care of changing the Root View Controller, not UIViewControllers.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention your error. Go to the storyboard and click on the ProfileSettingsViewController and go to the 3rd tab in the sidebar and there is a Storyboard ID. Set the name to "ProfileSettingsViewController" (or whatever you want) and it will find the controller. `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` searches the storyboard for a controller with the given Storyboard ID.

Comment: Hey @Gasim, I like your approach, but I'm given an error `'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'storyboard'` when I try to replicate your code in my AppDelegate.swift file. This error occurs at the `self.storyboard` line.

Comment: You need to add the storyboard to the AppDelegate: `var storyboard : UIStoryboard?` Or you can just remove `self.` and just do `var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())`. I use member variable because I have other functions that access it.

Comment: I used the storyboard variable method you listed, but still get an error highlighting `storyboard` on my `self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileSettingsViewController")`. Error message is `'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'storyboard'`

Comment: You should remove `self.` if your the variable is not a member variable. So, in your case, you are using `var storyboard` inside the function but you are using `self.storyboard`, which is trying to look for a member variable `storyboard`. Changing `self.storyboard` to `storyboard` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You set the Storyboard Identifier on the View Controller, right under the custom class setting in storyboards.

[image]

I would load the home screen and check if the user is logged in on `viewDidAppear:` within a dispatch_once block maybe, if user == nil then present the `loginViewController` using a segue or manually.

When the user logged in perform a rewind segue, send a message through a delegate or send a notification back to the home screen to dismiss it and refresh.