# Parse - Bypass Login in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am working to bypass login screen if the current user is not nil. To do this, I followed the recommendation posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856651/bypass-login-view-if-parse-user-is-logged-in). After running the code, I get a blank white view in the simulator without any errors showing. Here is the code:

```
 storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle());
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        print(currentUser)
        if currentUser != nil {
            self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController");
        }
```

Worth mentioning that HomeViewController is based on Tab navigation. What am I missing?

The setup I have is:

- App is launched and the first view is the Sign In view (with button for signup). This initial view is SignInViewController and I embedded a UINavigationController to it.
- User can login by providing credentials (if correct, segue is performed to redirect to HomeViewController)
- User can signup and follow the steps (multiple controllers). At the end they will be redirected to Home View Controller.

Comment: Looks like you should put `rootViewController = yourTabBarViewController`

Comment: How would that work? Because if user is not logged in, they will not be taken to the login or signup views.

Comment: Are you using a custom login view or the default parse one?

Comment: @TekShock custom I believe. I am updating my post with description of the set up I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your home tab bar controller has the identifier `"HomeViewController"` and your sign in view controller has the identifier `"SignInViewController"` and this code is in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` AppDelegate method:

```
storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() { // currentUser is not nil
    // set up app for valid in user
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController")
    return true // don't load the rootViewController from your storyboard (if you have an initial view set)
} else { // there is no current user
    // set up app for new or non logged in user
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInViewController")
    return true
}
```

From your comments, it sounds like you have a navigation controller with its root view controller being your sign in view controller, which is why when you segue to your tab bar controller, you get a navigation bar.

Since with my approach you're not getting the segue (and the sign in view controller's navigation bar), initialize a new `UINavigationController` and set its `rootViewController` to be your tab bar controller:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() { // currentUser is not nil
    // load tab bar controller
    let tabBarController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController")

    // initialize a new navigation controller with the tab bar controller as its rootViewController
    let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)

    // set the window's root view controller to be your new navigation controller
    self.window?.rootViewController = navC
}
```

Comment: This loads the HomeControllerView but without all the tabs that were there due to Tab Controller being in place. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @ksa_coder Is your tab bar controller in the storyboard?  Give it a Storyboard ID and replace HomeViewController with the tab bar controller's ID above.

Comment: ok did that....but the view is not fully showing correctly. The tab bar is showing correctly but the top nav bar totally disappeared across all tabs. I am glad you are helping out :)

Comment: @ksa_coder I think I understand what you mean.  I've updated my answer to wrap a your tab bar controller in a `UINavigationController`.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi JAL. although it did work as stated earlier when auto-logging in, I just discovered that when I login for the first time from SignInViewController, the nav bar doesn't show! Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @ksa_coder do the same thing that you do with the tab bar controller, embed your sign in view controller in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: what a boss! Thanks for the quick response mate.

Comment: Oops I thought it does automatically when I select an answer. My bad...fixing it

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more information?

This is how I check if someone is already logged on

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
                if currentUser != nil {
                  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfTheSegueIdentifier", sender: self)

            }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing here is within a specific view controller. The best practice to handling the check if user is logged in or not is in the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `PFUser.currentUser()` is not nil. You should use `PFUser.currentUser().username`. Use this code in your login/ signup **ViewController** (not AppDelegate (it works fine))

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if PFUser.currentUser().username != nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUE", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Two things to notice in this code: it is performed in the `viewDidAppear` method; not `viewDidLoad`. You cannot perform any segues until the view has appeared. Also, `SEGUE` is a temporary placeholder for your segue name. This segue should transfer the user over to the main page.

Note: the given code will show the `login/signup viewcontroller's` scene for about a second. I recommend putting a `UIImageView` on the `ViewController` that has the same frame as the view (covers the entire screen). If the username equals nil, you could put an else statement that says `imageView.alpha = 0` (set the alpha to 1 in the viewDidLoad). Hope this helps.